# Just Installed Virtualbox on Windows 10 host, Cannot Load Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Just installed 4.3.12, build 9926. For reasons I won't go into right now (extensive), the newest builds of VBox crash immediately in Windows 10 Home Edition.

Build 4.3.12 will actually start Vbox without crashing on startup. However I cannot start the Ubuntu1 that came with it. It launches a dialog that says **"Cannot access the kernel driver!"** and gives this error information:

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
```

I restarted my host as was recommended in the forums. No success.

After digging around (did not change any settings) I opened the Virtual Media Manager and the Ubuntu.vdi is located in E:\Ubuntu.vdi. I hovered over the VDI file and there is a VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND there. This makes sense to me since I have no E:\ connected to the host machine right now so it's looking for the .vdi in a non-existent location.

So what are my options here to get Ubuntu running? Should I download a new Ubuntu.vdi file and put it somewhere VBox can find it? If so, where is a secure place/URL to download the file from, and what is the optimal folder destination to download the .vdi to?

Comment: `.vdi` is a Virtual Disk Image. You can create one when you create a VM in VirtualBox. You don't download them, because they can get big very quick. (They are just disk images).

Comment: You are not using the current version of VirtualBox for one.  I have no problems with the actual current version of VirtualBox on my Windows 10 host.

Comment: @Ramhound I initially downloaded and installed VirtualBox 5.0.14 for Windows hosts. This application crashed immediately upon startup. 

Also tried running as administrator with no success. This was what I looked at first https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13665 however it is only the Technical Preview of Windows 10. I was not able to get a dump file. I was able to open Visual Studio debugger upon crashing and saw in the output window that most of the files in VBox "Could not load PDB files"

Comment: Earlier versions of Virtualbox has major problems with Windows 10 both as a Host and Guest.  Best to solve the application crash of the current version before proceeding.